# Don't post form input fields which are hidden?

Tags: forms, http-post, form-fields

I have created a form where input fields are shown/hidden based on selections and i like to post only the input fields which are visible. At the moment the values of the hidden input fields are also submitten

I checked the $_POST and i see

```
[chairs] => Array
    (
        [0] => chair-b-white
        [1] => chair-c-black
    )

    [num_of_chair-a-black] => 
    [num_of_chair-a-white] => 
    [num_of_chair-a-gray] => 
    [num_of_chair-b-black] => 
    [num_of_chair-b-white] => 2
    [num_of_chair-b-gray] => 
    [num_of_chair-c-black] => 5
    [num_of_chair-c-white] => 
    [num_of_chair-c-gray] =>
```

Is there a way to skip posting input fields which are empty?

Comment: You can do this with JavaScript. Do you already use a JS library?

Comment: @Jasper yes, jquery + bootstrap + bootstrapvalidator. btw i am hide/showing the divs by `    $("#chairs").change(function() {
                    $('.hide-el-chairs').hide();
                    
                    $("#chairs option:selected").each(function() {
                        var str = $(this).attr("value");
                        $('#num_of_' + str).show();
                        $('.num_of_' + str + "_label").show();
                    });
                });`

Answer (score 3):

I assume you toggle the fields' visibility using javascript. When hiding them you can also set them to `disabled`. Disabled form fields are not submitted to the server.

Comment: hmm, i hide the div they are in. so i have to disable all childern input fields?

Comment: Ah, yes, you must disable the fields individually inside each div you hide.

Comment: hmm i can enble them but the toggle doesn't work. In the hidden div i have all the select menus disabled and `$('.hide-el-chairs').hide();
    $("#chairs").change(function() {
                    $('.hide-el-chairs').hide(); $("#chairs option:selected").each(function() {
                        var str = $(this).attr("value");
                         $('#num_of_' + str).prop('disabled', false);$('#num_of_' + str).show(); $('.num_of_' + str + "_label").show(); }); });`
Now the input fields are enable but when the select menu are hidden again i can't make the select menu disabled again

Comment: Ok i think i have got it. I select all input fields by
`$('#option-chairs :input').prop('disabled',true);`